# Upload resized image on amazon S3 with PHP SDK

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a script wich resize and crop an image and I would like to upload the image on my amazon S3 on the fly.

The problem is that I get an error message when I try to run my script because I guess the sourcefile is not recognized as a direct path from the disk ($filepath). Do you have any idea to get through this situation?

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message '**You must specify a non-null value for the Body or SourceFile parameters.**' in phar:///var/www/submit/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/UploadBodyListener.php:...

```
$myResizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
        imagecopyresampled($myResizedImage,$myImage,0,0,0,0, $width, $height, $origineWidth, $origineHeight);

$myImageCrop = imagecreatetruecolor(612,612);
        imagecopy( $myImageCrop, $myResizedImage, 0,0, $posX, $posY, 612, 612);

//Save image on Amazon S3

     require 'aws.phar';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = 'yol';
$keyname = 'image_resized';                    
$filepath = $myImageCrop;

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'private-key',
    'secret' => 'secrete-key',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1'

    ));

try {
    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
        'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
        'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
    ));

    // Print the URL to the object.
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Could You Post the Full Code.I am facing the same kind of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `SourceFile` of the upload to `$filepath`, which is assigned from `$myImageCrop = imagecreatetruecolor(...)`. As such, it's not actually a path at all — it's a GD image resource. You can't upload these to S3 directly.

You'll need to either write that image out to a file (using e.g. `imagejpeg()` + `file_put_contents()`), or run the upload using data in memory (again, from `imagejpeg()` or similar).

Comment: it means that I have to upload my image on my EC2 instance and then on my S3?

Comment: I tried : `$filepath = imagejpeg($myImageCrop);` without success

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert your image resource to an actual string containing image data. You can use this function to achieve this:

```
function image_data($gdimage)
{
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($gdimage);
    return(ob_get_clean());
}
```

Comment: Good solution for those who don't want to save the file. Instead of `SourceFile` use `'Body'=>image_data($img)`

Answer (score 1):

```
     require 'aws.phar';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = 'kkkk';
$keyname = 'test';
// $filepath should be absolute path to a file on disk  

$newFielName = tempnam(null,null); // take a llok at the tempnam and adjust parameters if needed
imagejpeg($myImageCrop, $newFielName, 100); // use $newFielName in putObjectFile()

$filepath = $newFielName;

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'jjj',
    'secret' => 'kkk',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1'

    ));

try {
    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
        'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
        'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
    ));

    // Print the URL to the object.
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```